# New Compiler - Using Cout?

Tags: c++, iostream

I've searched for a solution to my problem, and the posted ones don't seem to work. I am trying to run the following in Visual Studio 2012. I have previously used Eclipse for my programming, and am adjusting to the new IDE.

```
    class
    IntSLLNode{
    public:
    int info;
    IntSLLNode *next;

    IntSLLNode(){
    next = 0;
    }

  IntSLLNode (int el, IntSLLNode *ptr= 0) {
  info = el;
  next = ptr;
  }

};

int main(){

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

IntSLLNode *p = new IntSLLNode(18);
cout << *p;

return;

}
```

When I try to run that, it gives me an error under cout. I have included iostream and the std namespace as I normally do. Is that not correct? Can anyone assist me in getting this to work, because I quite prefer the look of the Visual Studio IDE and would like to continue using it.

Comment: it's better if you edit your question adding the error message you get from your IDE

Comment: Also note that "`using namespace std`" is many more characters than `std::`, so in this case it doesn't even save you any typing.

Comment: Pretty sure this wouldn't compile in eclipse either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that the lines

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

should not be inside of `main`.  Instead, they should be at the top level of the program.  Your program should look more like

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/* Other definitions */

int main() {
    IntSLLNode *p = new IntSLLNode(18);
    cout << *p;
}
```

Additionally, you have the statement

```
return;
```

inside of a function that returns an `int`, which isn't allowed.  Try changing this to either

```
return 0;
```

or, since this is `main`, just skip the `return` all together.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, there is no overloaded `operator<<` for `IntSLLNode` objects, so `cout << *p;` will still be an error.  Perhaps `cout << p;`?

Comment: Thanks! Isn't return; equivalent to return 0;, though?

I want to output the value of the pointer p, so I have dereferenced it. Not so?

Comment: @user2395694 `return;` is not equivalent to `return 0;`.

Comment: Get rid of the pointer period imo. And the `using` part can go inside `main` at least.

Comment: @user2395694 dereferencing a pointer means getting the thing that it points to.  So if by the value of the pointer you mean the address it's pointing to, you just use the pointer as is.  `std::ostream` (which is the type of `std::cout`) prints out the address of pointers when you pass them using the stream insertion operator (`<<`).

Comment: If you don't want the address of the node to print out, but rather some string representation of it, you need to tell the compiler what a human-readable representation of the object might look like.  You do this by overloading `operator<<`.  For instance:

`std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const IntSLLNode& node)
{
   os << '(' << node.info << ' ';
   if (node.next)
      os << *node.next;
   os << ')';
   return os;
}`

Comment: `using namespace std;` should rather be inside the function than outside. It doesn't need to be in / apply to global scope and to limit it to where it's necessary / useful would be better IMO.